# An integer when divided by $5$ and $13$ leaves residues $4$ and $7$ respectively

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

Find an integer when divided by $5$ and $13$ leaves residues $4$ and $7$ respectively. (Without Modular Arithmetic).

I don't know if it is right, but I got this
$$n=5x+4=13y+7$$

$$n=5(x-11)+59=13(y-4)+59$$
The $\operatorname{lcd}(5,13)=65$

So our number is every number like $n=65k+59$

I'll be glad if you enlighten me it.

Comment: It seems that your solution is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

${\bf Brute\  force}:\ \ 5\,\Bbb Z+\color{green}4 = \{\ldots, \color{#c00}{-6},-1,\color{green}4,9,13,\ldots\}$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \  13\Bbb Z+\color{orange}7 = \{\ldots, \color{#c00}{-6},\color{orange}7,20,\ldots\}\,\ $ so $\,\ n\equiv \color{#c00}{-6}\pmod{65 = \rm{lcm}(5,13)}\ $

$\bf Algorithmically,$ using CRT

$\quad\,\  {\rm mod}\ 5\!:\,\ n \equiv 4\equiv 7\!+\!13y \equiv 2\!-\!2y\iff 2\equiv -2y\iff \color{#0a0}{y\equiv -1}$

$\quad$ so its true iff $\ n = 7\!+\!13y = 7 \!+\! 13(\color{#0a0}{-1\!+\!5k}) = -6+65k,\ k\in\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

$5x - 13y = 7-4 = 3 \Rightarrow 5x = 15y + 3 - 2y \Rightarrow x = 3y + \dfrac{3-2y}{5} \Rightarrow 5\mid 3-2y \Rightarrow 3-2y = 5k \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{3-5k}{2} = \dfrac{3-k}{2} - 2k \Rightarrow 2\mid 3-k \Rightarrow 3-k = 2h \Rightarrow k = 3-2h \Rightarrow 3 - 5k = 3 - 5(3-2h) = -12 + 10h \Rightarrow y = \dfrac{3-5k}{2} = \dfrac{-12+10h}{2} = 5h-6 \Rightarrow n = 13y+7 = 13(5h-6)+7 = 65h-71 = 65(h-1) - 6 = 65t-6 = 65(t-1) + 59=65m+59, m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Surely this could use some vertical spacing.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Use inspection :   $5x = 13 y + 3 \\
13(1) + 3 = 16 \\
13(2) + 3 = 29 \\
13(3) + 3 = 42 \\
13(4) + 3 = 5(11) \quad\checkmark \\
\therefore \forall k\in\mathbb Z: 5 (11+13k) = 13(4+5k) +3 \\[2ex]
{\forall k\in\Bbb Z, \exists n\in\Bbb Z: \underline{\quad n = 59 + 65 k\quad}}
$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $13\times 2=26\equiv 1 \mod 5$

and $5\times 8=40\equiv 1 \mod 13$

So that $26x+40y \equiv x \mod 5; \equiv y \mod 13$ so we can put $x=4, y=7$ to obtain $104+280=384$ as one solution. We can obtain other solutions by adjusting by a multiple of $65$ - $390$ is obvious giving $-6$ and then $59$ by adding $65$.

The merit of this method, which relates closely to the Chinese Remainder Theorem (and Lagrange Interpolation for polynomials) is that it provides an automatic solution whatever values of $x$ and $y$ are given.

Comment: Sorry, it said without modular arithmetic in the question, but this is too neat not to mention, and the modular arithmetic is mainly shorthand which can be undone as in some of the other answers. I thought it would be informative to show a general method.

Comment: No problem !! +1 ;P

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for any such integer, so note that $2\cdot13-5\cdot5=1$, now $13$ divides $1+5\cdot5$ and $5$ divides $1-2\cdot3$, so
$$4(1+5\cdot5)+7(1-2\cdot13)=4\cdot26-7\cdot25=-71$$
is an example of such integer.